# compare time using sql query

Tags: sql, time, comparison

I am working on attendance management system using php and mysql. I want to display the total number of times a person spending less than 9 hrs a day. `timein` and `timout` is been stored in database. I used the query:

```
SELECT * FROM presence 
WHERE 'timeout' - 'timein' < 9 AND  uid=".$uid1[$i]."
AND date BETWEEN'".$date1."' AND '".$date2."'");

echo "<td align='center'>".mysql_num_rows($recordset)."</td>"; 

$lateout1 = mysql_num_rows($recordset);
```

But nothing is displayed. Please help me to display the number of days for all users spends less than 9 hrs a day.

Comment: I am not sure about php but don't you think you need to store result of your query in recordset.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! **[Please format your code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)**.

Comment: What is the data type of `timein` and `timeout` columns? Better yet post `CREATE TABLE` statement for `presence` table.

Comment: i am using recordset in my program ,by mistake i left it here .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
select uid,count(uid) as no_of_days from presence 
where (time_to_sec(timediff(timeout, timein )) / 3600)<9  
and date> $date1 and date< $date2 
group by uid.
```